Solving a CMake Error in building tensorflow library
Tried using CMake (3.29.0) to build the tensorflow library (2.5.0) with an arm linux gnueabihf 4.9 compiler. Met these errors after using make on makefiles, which were generated by cmake gui:
C:/tensorflow-2.5.0/tflite_build/xnnpack/src/f32-vrnd/gen/vrndd-neonv8-x4.c: In function 'xnn_f32_vrndd_ukernel__neonv8_x4': C:/tensorflow-2.5.0/tflite_build/xnnpack/src/f32-vrnd/gen/vrndd-neonv8-x4.c:31:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'vrndmq_f32' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] const float32x4_t vy0123 = vrndmq_f32(vx0123); ^ C:/tensorflow-2.5.0/tflite_build/xnnpack/src/f32-vrnd/gen/vrndd-neonv8-x4.c:31:32: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'float32x4_t' using type 'int' const float32x4_t vy0123 = vrndmq_f32(vx0123); ^ C:/tensorflow-2.5.0/tflite_build/xnnpack/src/f32-vrnd/gen/vrndd-neonv8-x4.c:37:28: error: incompatible types when initializing type 'float32x4_t' using type 'int' const float32x4_t vy = vrndmq_f32(vx); ^ make[2]: *** [_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/XNNPACK.dir/src/f32-vrnd/gen/vrndd-neonv8-x4.c.o] Error 1 make[1]: *** [_deps/xnnpack-build/CMakeFiles/XNNPACK.dir/all] Error 2 make: *** [all] Error 2
Tried adding -mfpu-neon=neon for c flags and cxx flags because it may seem that is an issue with the implicit declaration of the function (possibly from neon.h) but does not seem to solve the problem
